# Why do I get this result with SymPy's parse_expr

Tags: python, parsing, sympy, expr

I wrote the following code:

```
simplification = parse_expr(str_expression, evaluate=True)
expression = parse_expr(str_expression, evaluate=False)

if expression == simplification:
   msg = "Couldn't simplify!"
else:
   msg = "Simplified:"
```

I thought that if the expression is the same whether or not it has been evaluated, that must mean that it's already as simplified as it can be.
But for some reason, for

```
str_expression = "s+5"
```

I get that this expression is false:

```
expression == simplification
```

Does anybody know why? How do I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although the two expressions print the same their internal representations are different as the store the args in a different order. The `doit` method is usually supposed to undo the effect of `evaluate=False`:

```
In [10]: expression
Out[10]: s + 5

In [11]: simplification
Out[11]: s + 5

In [12]: expression.args
Out[12]: (s, 5)

In [13]: simplification.args
Out[13]: (5, s)

In [14]: expression.doit().args
Out[14]: (5, s)

In [15]: expression.doit() == simplification
Out[15]: True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem. Unfortunately I think it created I new one. before, when I entered "a*a" I got "a^2" as a simplification. Now, it presents "a^2" and writes: "Couldn't simplify!", even though it is simplified.